# Алгоритм поиска в инвертированном индексе

Tags: поиск, алгоритм

Здравствуйте всем.

Понадобился алгоритм поиска в инвертированном индексе, выглядит примерно так:

Москва 1 2 4

Пекин 1 3 6 9

Лондон 3 8 9

То есть при запросе Москва Пекин, поиск должен выдать цифру один.
Никак не могу придумать такой алгоритм, строки я уже обработал значение строк  тоже(циферки после названий).Все это находится в Map структуре в виде пары ключ - значение (String - int[])

Названий не обязательно три их может быть больше.. Да и циферок тоже разное количество

**UPD!**

Объясню еще раз, у нас есть с файл с такими строками:

1. Москва 1 2 4
2. Пекин 1 3 6 9
3. Лондон 3 8 9

Создаем Map, ключом в нем будет слова, а значениями цифры, то есть <String,int[]>
Есть запрос(Строка) - Москва Пекин, разделяем строку на пробелы, ищем совпадения в Map,е с ключом и выводим значения, то есть для строки Москва Пекин у на будет вывод:
[1,2,4]
[1,3,6,9]

Сама изюминка заключается в том, что вот в этих значениях надо найти одинаковые элементы, мы видим - 1, это и будет выводом программы)

Пока остановился на этом(Где Slova это массив слов, а Base,собс-но, Map структура с ключом и значением):

```
 if (Slova[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Basa.getKey())) { 
    System.out.println(Basa.getValue()); 
 }
```

**UPD2!**

*2) в этих данных (массивы) найти совпадающие по значениям элементы*
Вот так,одинаковые цифры найти.

Заранее благодарю, за описание подобного алгоритма!

Comment: А что такое «инвертированный индекс», простите?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю задачу, вот вам LINQ:

    requestedCities
        .Select(city => new HashSet<int>(map[city]))
        .Aggregate((intersection, next) =>
                       {
                           intersection.IntersectWith(next);
                           return intersection;
                       });

Comment: Ну я же написал, эта такая структура данных, дескать ключ(много ключей) и много значений, в нашем случае ключ это название города,  а значения это цифры. Ухх ну и алгоритм..)) Не разобраться, если честно

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81 Смотреть категорию пример, вот нужно найти одинаковые числа в значениях

Comment: @IvanS: Так ничего сложного. Берём для каждого упомянутого в строке города множество ключей, и подсчитываем пересечение этих множеств.

Comment: @IvanS, а при запросе Пекин Лондон ответ -- цифра 3?

а для Москва Лондон -- не найдено?

Я правильно понял, что Вы имели в виду?

Comment: Вот и проблемка тут закралась.. Так как пишу в основном на Java, то вот  if (Slova[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Basa.getKey())) {         System.out.println(Basa.getValue());
}  То есть значения я вот тут получил, При запросе Москва Пекин вывод, соот-но, [1,2,4] и [1,3,6,9] А как дальше то?) Сохранить что то в массив или как

Comment: @avp, да, почти, только там же еще есть цифра 9, так что для Пекин Лондон результат 3 и 9

Comment: @IvanS, если хотите, что бы Вам толком помогли, то лучше обрисуйте задачу на уровне предметной области  

(что на самом деле Вам нужно сделать),

а не в терминах Ваших структур данных.

Comment: @IvanS, вас же просили - нормальным языком, а не как вы её себе соструктурировали. Насколько я понял, нужно:

1) найти данные, ключи для которых заданы на входе

2) в этих данных (массивы) найти совпадающие по значениям элементы, индексы которых минимальны.

Так?